# Search for specific words in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
select * from data WHERE name LIKE  '%Hi There%';
```

returns this:

```
Hi There John
Hi There
Man Hi There
Hi There Mate
Hi Theres Alice
Hi Theree Man
```

I only want `Hi There John`, `Hi There Mate`, `Hi There` and `Man Hi There` to be returned because they contain `Hi There` specifically. `Hi Theres Alice` and `Hi Theree Man` should not appear.

How can this be done, simply?

Comment: Please, don't change your question eliminating all the content that where relevant for those who already have made an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE
    name LIKE 'Hi There %' OR
    name LIKE '% Hi There %' OR
    name LIKE '%Hi There';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression instead of `LIKE`. Then you can use `[:<:]` and `[:>:]` to match word boundaries.

```
select * from data WHERE name RLIKE  '[:<:]Hi There[:>:]';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to get exactly the rows with the values you want. A query that gives you what you need would look something like this:

```
select * from data WHERE name REGEXP '{^\bHi There\b\s*.*$}';
```